# Incidence Matrix of Experimental Design Using R language Program

Tags: r

I am working on educational assignment to produce an Incidence matrix from a BIB design using R language software.
 I found a web page http://wiki.math.yorku.ca/index.php/R:_Incidence_matrix  related to problem. But it produces Data matrix instead of Incidence matrix. can anyone please help me out with R language code. the codes for obtaining the BIB design matrix is:

```
b=4                                  # Number of Blocks  
t=8                                  # Number of Column
z=c(1,2,3)                           # Shift
m=NULL
y=c(0)
w=c(y,cumsum(z) %%t)                 # cumsum() is for the running totals
p=seq(from=0, to=t-1, by=1)
l=NULL

for(i in 1:b)  
 {
     for(j in 1:t) 
        {
            l=c(l,rep((w[i]+p[j]+t)%% t))
         }
  }
#"BIB design" it has 4 rows (blocks b) and 8 column (treatments t)
x= matrix(c(l),nrow=b,ncol=t,byrow = TRUE)  
 print (x)

0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7   
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    0   
3    4    5    6    7    0    1    2    
6    7    0    1    2    3    4    5
```

(it can be generated at any t-treatments and b-blocks size generally)
using above design matrix x (4*8). i need the following Incidence matrix (8*8)

```
1   1   0   1    0    0   1    0       
0   1   1   0    1    0   0    1        
1   0   1   1    0    1   0    0     
0   1   0   1    1    0   1    0       
0   0   1   0    1    1   0    1       
0   1   0   0    1    0   1    1   
1   0   1   0    0    1   0    1
```

Consider Design Matrix Column wise and generate Incidence Matrix Row wise. For example the 1st column of x is

```
0   
1    
6    
3
```

Now see the 1st row of the required Incidence Matrix (IM).

```
1   1   0   1    0    0   1    0
```

At 1st place of x is 0 so put 1 in 1st place of IM.

At 2nd place of x is 1 so put also 1 at the 2nd place of IM.

Here 2 is missing in the column of x so put 0 at 3rd place of IM.

x contains 3 so put 1 at 4th place, 4 and 5 is missing put two 0's in a row consecutively.

X has 6 put 1 at 7th place and 7 is missing put 0 at 8th place of IM.

Take 2nd column of x and similarly filled 2nd row of IM. If the particular number (0 to 7) is present put one otherwise zero.

I hope, i make it clear for every one now.

Comment: what does the "this" represent?  Getting a matrix of all 1's is straightforward. Where are those 1's supposedly coming from? Why would they not be 0, etc?

Comment: Do you mean a [bib design](http://www.cafepress.com/make/custom-bibs) or a [bib design](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/agricolae/docs/design.bib). Where does your bib design output come from? What is `x`?

Comment: Zahar, saying "I need this matrix" does not allow anyone to give you a helpful answer.  **You must explain how you are calculating your final matrix**.  What formula?  If you do it with pen and paper, how would you do it?

Comment: ``apply(x,2, `%in%`, x = 0:7)`` will create a logical matrix doing what you want (Will post as soon as it is reopened) -- The question makes sense now!

Comment: @RicardoSaporta. I am sorry for that. actually it is the part of my assignment. I have tried many techniques and codes (got online and self made) but could not meet the requirement that's why I use  the word"need"

Comment: @mnel... it is not worlking

Comment: @user1881159 - what about `apply(x,2, \`%in%\`, x=unique(as.vector(x)))`

Comment: @thelatemail. it looks work accurately. but in TRUE and FALSE not in 0 ans 1 please guide further.

Comment: `TRUE` and `FALSE` are essentially 0 and 1 `apply(x,2, \`%in%\`, x=unique(as.vector(x)))+0` will make it spit it out as intended.

Comment: @thelatemail. it works in o and 1 but not producing required results

Comment: The real question is the problem outlined here [matrix assignment failing within lapply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735525/matrix-assignment-failing-within-lapply).

Comment: @mnel. I tried my level best to get required results using all given codes on the page but failed. Can you please do this i my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the x matrix different to have two identical entries in one column I get this logic to work:

```
x[4,1] <- 1
t( apply(x, 2, function(z){ ret <- numeric(8)
                            for( i in seq_along(z) ){ret[z[i]+1] <- ret[z[i]+1]+ 1}
                            ret}) )

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    2    0    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1    1    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    1
[6,]    1    0    0    1    0    1    1    0
[7,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    1
[8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    1
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the effort. But when there is repetition of an element in a specific block, it should covert into repetition time, but it still gives 1 for example, the block column (0,1,3,1) with 5 treatments (t) should generate the row (1,2,0,1,0) because element 1 in the block column repeat twice.

Comment: @mnel. please put t=5 in the code (mentioned in the Question) and run it in R and get x, that x contains 1st column 0,1,3,1. here number "1" repeat twice, in result, first row of Incidence matrix (IM) should be 1,2,0,1,0. is this make you clear?.

Comment: Perhaps it would have been better to make t=5 your example data set so it was clear that you wanted the sum not just an indicator of presence. That is not obvious from your description in the question.

Comment: @Dear DWin. I am waiting for your response.

Comment: It's in there. I replaced the earlier code and  show it was working as requested. Two at the second entry when there are two ones in the sequence of positins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how you are going by getting your intended output. However, the reason you are getting a much longer output than you anticipated is possibly due to the `[ as.factor(vec),]` part of your code .

`as.factor(vec)` is taking your `4x4 matrix` and turning it into a single vector of 16 elements. (Well, technically, vec is already a vector, but let's not confuse things).

```
as.factor(vec)
[1] 0 1 3 2 1 2 0 3 2 3 1 0 3 0 2 1
Levels: 0 1 2 3
```

You are then using that as an index, which is repeating values of A.

---

** By the way, are you *sure* you should get a matrix of all 1's?  And not perhaps just 1's on the diagonal?

```
contrasts( as.factor(vec), contrasts =FALSE)
#    0 1 2 3
#  0 1 0 0 0
#  1 0 1 0 0
#  2 0 0 1 0
#  3 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Dear I am new and not much familiar with R. I have a BIB design and i need to  convert it into Incidence matrix. I got these all codes online.

Comment: Thats not a problem.  It is just not very clear what you are asking for.

Comment: @user1881159 You know what is better than "sending u the whole program code"?  Being able to create a clear, concise, and answerable question.

Comment: @user1881159:  Perhaps take some time to establish where specifically you are having an issue and describing how you would like to obtain the solution you are seeking.

Comment: @Dason the length of the program is out of comment range, can I please E-mail you?

Comment: @user1881159. Nobody will want you to email them the code. You can edit your question...... Please edit your question.

Comment: I suspect that even with the program code, it will still be unclear why you are expecting to get a matrix of all 1's.  It would be a lot more helpful if you would elaborate on this